# Trouble with Specific lines, possible series of puns

Tags: grammar, meaning, song-lyrics

I'm having trouble with a specific set of lines [in this song](http://vocaloidlyrics.wikia.com/wiki/%E5%8F%8D%E8%8A%BB%E3%81%AE%E5%8D%B0%E8%B1%A1_(Hansuu_no_Inshou)).

> 本当は噛み締めてなんかいやしない
>
> I really didn't understand it
>
> 明日の日付も今日も飲み込んじまえ
>
> But I understood it completely today and tomorrow
>
> 咀嚼の時間も　緊急停車にも気付きはしない
>
> When I understood it, I hadn't realized (I had understood it) when we
>   were at an emergency stop.

This is my best guess, but I'm not sure about these lines, especially the last one ("The time of understanding, and at the emergency stop, the realization was not there" is what I took from it literally) and also since every word I translated "understand" could also mean "chew," which confused me, although I went with understand since in context chewing wouldn't really make sense.

I guess what I'm asking is this: Is my interpretation correct? Am I missing something about the whole "chewing" thing?

Thanks!

Comment: If those are your *translations*, I would suggest starting with more **literal** translations and then work on *interpreting* them.

Answer (score 1):

As A.Ellett commented, a good interpretation can never be obtained without a good literal translation. So here is a literal translation:

> 本当は噛み締めてなんかいやしない
>   In reality, he is not even chewing.
>
> 明日の日付も今日も飲み込んじまえ
>   Swallow up (the date of) tomorrow, and even today.
>
> 咀嚼の時間も　緊急停車にも気付きはしない
>   He doesn't notice the time for mastication or an emergency stop.

(I used "he" as the subject because, [as I said elsewhere](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/47879/5010), I feel the whole song is depicted from the third person's viewpoint.)

噛みしめる can also mean "to relish" of "to enjoy", and 咀嚼 can also mean "to rethink deeply".

The whole lyrics are fairly vague, but basically the song is about a mysterious long-distance train that runs forever whatever happens. The train does not have a passenger or even a sane conductor, but it keeps on running. No one knows why it's running.

So in this context, these four lines vaguely expresses that someone is "in a trance." The person is not thinking. He doesn't care for what's happening around him, and even an emergency stop signal will not stop him. He doesn't even care for the flow of time. Still, the train keeps on running.

Anyway, the word choice of these song is basically vague, random and peculiar. The song is not meant to be logically interpreted. It may not be very meaningful to seek for a natural interpretation too much.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think that, in line 3, 時間 could be taken for "length of time" and not "time for"? To me, "He doesn't notice how long he has been chewing or even an emergency stop" makes more sense and goes with line 2.

Comment: ＠Smoothie Xの時間 usually means "time for X", not "time taken for X".